# I cannot add comments on cross validated!

Tags: support, tags, comment

I have been a user on cross validated website for quite some time. Around a month ago, I was suddenly unable to add tags to my questions or to add comments to any question. I have contacted the website and they replied me that they have not heard of or seen such a problem before. Is anybody having this problem too?

Note: other websites, such as stackoverflow, are working fine

Hi @gung, I couldn't post a reply to this question so I am answering you here. The support have replied me asking to restart my computer (which I did, yet failed to add comments) and to tell them how to reproduce the problem. I replied that the problem can be reproduced very easily and, I am just unable to add a comment! I haven't heard from them back yet, but I wanted to see if anybody have had the same problem before.

What happens exactly: in comments: I type my comment, then hit "add comment" and and everything I typed disappears.
With tags: I type in the tags I want but they do not show as suggestions, so I am not able to add them.

Comment: (I have never had this problem.) This seems like an issue for the developers, did they say anything about trying to fix it for you?

Comment: Sounds like some of the comment JavaScript wasn't loaded properly off the site, or that the cached version on your browser is corrupt. Can you clear your browser cache and try again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to be using Internet Explorer in "compatibility mode". This breaks the site in numerous ways - you will need to turn it off. Please follow the instructions [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-10) to do so.

Related: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/why-cant-i-post-a-comment-anymore

Comment: This comment is a test to see whether this worked or not :)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks buddy :)